# Q: yii2 dataProvider doesn't display join attributes

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I have a relation between User and Thesis and my dataProvider just displays user attributes and not thesis'ones in the Gridview. Is there a better way to print join attributes than: ['attribute'] => ['table.attribute']?

model:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Request::find()->joinWith('user')->joinWith('thesis')->where(['thesis.staff'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'title',
        ['attribute' => 'thesis',
        'value' => 'thesis.title'],
        //'company',
        'description:ntext',
        'duration',
        ['attribute' => 'user'
        'value' => 'user.id'],
        //'requirements',
        //'course',
        'n_person',
        'ref_person',
        'is_visible:boolean',
        //'created_at',
        //'staff',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SearchRequest();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, but you should use `->joinWith(['user',
    'thesis th' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
        $query->where(['th.staff'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    }
])` and you can specify multiple relations as array in a single call to  `joinWith()`.

Comment: also which search model is it that you are using for the gridview ?

Comment: My $searchModel comes from SearchRequest->search() which is above, anyway it still doesn't print the thesis attributes. Now, my relation is User-Student-Thesis with User-Student (0-1,1-1) and Student-Thesis (N-N) that creates a new table/model called Request. I guess the problem could be in Request model since joinWith() use those get methods.

Comment: What is Request model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the relation getters on your model.

On your Thesis model, you need to add something like

```
public function getUser0 () {
    return $this->hasOne(\your\user\model\location\User::className(), ['id' => 'user']);
}
```

Having this on your model will populate via lazy-load the user relation when you call Thesis::user0, in your case, something like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        /// ---- other attributes
        ['attribute' => 'user0.name'],
        /// ---- other attributes
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I had a getUser() function and not a getUser0(), thank you. Can you tell me why this occurred?

Comment: I believe Model::getUser does not override the built-in getter for the $user attribute, so you need to have the relation getter named something else

Answer (score 0):

Is better to add your code after **$this->load($params);**

My example is:

```
.
.
.
$this->load($params);
if (!$this->validate()) {
    // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
    // $query->where('0=1');
    return $dataProvider;
}
$query->joinWith('user');
$query->joinWith('thesis');
$query->andFilterWhere(['thesis.staff'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
.
.
.
```